# Split MS Access Database a single user experiences error "Not a Valid Filename"

Tags: ms-access

I have split Microsoft access database  that is being used by multiple users at a multiple locations. I have a login screen that comes on when a user first opens the database. We are all using the same version of Access. For every user but one it is working perfectly. For that one user if they click on the combo box to select their location or click the login button, they get an error that says "Not a Valid File Name". I have more than 30 users of the database but it is only this one user that is experiencing this issue. I am utterly lost to know what is causing this error or what makes this user unique.

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X95s.png)

We checked to make sure she had read/write permissions on the folder where the backend of the database is located, by having her open and save a text file in the folder and that worked fine. I even moved a copy of the front end into that folder and had her try to access it from there and she received the same "Not a Valid File Name" error. Then I attempted to login to that same copy there and did not receive that error it worked fine. Is there anything in the database that could be causing this error or is it a permissions error or maybe a firewall error?

Comment: Try her login on another computer that works for other users. Try other user login on her computer. If she was able to navigate to folder to save text file, then must have appropriate drive path. Maybe have to reinstall Access or even rebuild computer. I once had issue with a procedure not working properly on one computer, replaced computer and user had no more issue.

Comment: Maybe check that the user has all the required VBA references used by the front-end, and that they're the same versions as on the other computers that work?

You will need to debug / step-through each of the procedures you mentioned (combo-box click and login click) and see at what step the error comes up.

Comment: It might be worth posting the code for those two procedures here as well.

Answer (score 0):

well based on that you can login to that same copy there and did not receive that error it worked fine....then it most likely is the log-in logic...  the message maybe is just misleading and it actually is not a system/infrastructure issue...

obviously the log-in is intended, by design, to keep people out that don't pass muster... so you need to inspect the vba behind the log-in event....